# Can a CFG end have a non-terminal symbol in the middle of it?

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars, context-free

What is the correct way to write a CFG?

```
A -> B C' E
C' -> C
C' -> null
```

or

```
A -> B C'
C' -> C E
C' -> E
```

Comment: What are `E` and `null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of those are valid context-free grammars. (For the same language.) The requirement for a context-free grammar is just that the left side of the production must have exactly one non-terminal, which both of them satisfy. (Usually, to make this more clear, we'd have a convention like non-terminals are uppercase and variables are lower-case, and we'd specify the start symbol. But it looks clear that you have $A$ and $C'$ as nonterminals and the rest terminals, with $A$ being the start symbol.)

Comment: Maybe the second one is an attempt on conversion to CNF?

Comment: To be fully precise, the right hand side can't be $\epsilon$ (`null` above) either. But one of the standard transformations is to eliminate productions with $\epsilon$ on the right hand side, so in practice this is accepted.

Comment: @vonbrand - I'm not sure what you mean; a context-free grammar is allowed to have epsilon-transitions.

Comment: @usul, if yu go by Chomsky's hierarchy of grammars, if it has $\epsilon$ as a RHS in a production, it is an unrestricted grammar (type 0). Nitpicking is one of my hobbies ;-)

Comment: @vonbrand - It is good to be picky about correctness, but I think there's a mistake somewhere. Otherwise no language containing the empty string would be context-free.

Can you check your source? I am looking at Sipser's *Intro to the Theory of Computation* and there is no such restriction on CFGs ... even when put in Chomsky Normal Form, the start symbol is explicitly allowed to transition to $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @usul, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy. If you allow $\epsilon$ on the RHS, type 2 grammars aren't a subset of type 1 grammars.

Comment: @vonbrand - ok, this raises a couple good points. First, even in the Chomsky hierarchy, you are allowed to have a rule of $S \to \varepsilon$ for the start symbol $S$. Second, Type 2 Grammars in Chomsky Normal Form are NOT the same as Context Free Grammars. Because both grammars generate the Context-Free Languages, they're considered basically equivalent (any $G$ in CNF is automatically a CFG, and any CFG can be converted to CNF). But even though the Context-Free Languages are the same for both, they are not the same thing.

Comment: I don't know if I stated that well but the key point is that CNF is a special form that context-free grammars may be converted to with specific restrictions, one of which (as you say) is that it cannot have $\varepsilon$ in the right-hand-side except in special circumstances.

Comment: @usul, it is allowed, but _only_ for type 0 grammars. Type 1 have length(LHS) $\le$ length(RHS) (no $\epsilon$!), type 2 (CFG) have length(LHS) = 1 (just one non-terminal), type 3 are type 2 with at most one non-terminal in the RHS, at the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7389/discussion-between-usul-and-vonbrand)

Answer (score 2):

Conditions for  Famous Grammars:
(YOU MUST NEVER FORGET THE FOLLOWING)

1) Regular Grammars  : Grammar That is either Right linear or Left Linear Grammar

This is also called Type 3 Grammar

2) Context Free Grammar : LHS must be exactly 1 Non-terminal , RHS can be any String of terminals and Non--Terminals.

This is also called Type 2 Grammar

3) Context Sensitive Grammar  : LHS can be any String , RHS can be any String of terminals and Non--Terminals such  that  for each production , length of LHS string must be  less than or equal to length of RHS string

This is also called Type 1 Grammar

4) Recursively Enumerable Grammar  : LHS can be any String , RHS can be any String of terminals and Non--Terminals

This is also called Type 0 Grammar

:)

Comment: To be precise, what you describe as context-sensitive grammars are actually noncontracting (or monotonic) grammars. Context-sensitive grammars have the requirement that all rules are in the form $\alpha A \beta \rightarrow \alpha \gamma \beta$, where $A$ is a nonterminal and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are strings of terminals and nonterminals ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be empty), therefore any context-sensitive grammar is also noncontracting. These two definitions are equivalent (i.e. they describe the same set of languages) and *together* form what is called the set of Type-1 grammars.

Comment: Also, technically speaking, recursively enumerable and noncontracting grammars don't really make a distinction between terminal and nonterminal symbols, and the LHS in Type 0 grammars cannot be empty.